# iphone data formatter for last modified file

Tags: ios, ios4

```
NSString * last_modified = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"]];

NSLog(@"Last-Modified: %@ ", last_modified );
NSString *dateString = @"Tue, 11 Dec 2012 13:22:57 GMT";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date:%@",date);
```

Here the date time is showing which is not equal time to current india time. Please gave me a suggestion

Thanks,
Vijayan

Answer (score 0):

the time is in GMT

to convert it to local timezone with `setTimeZone` to `NSDateFormatter`